# VLC is unable to open the MRL when specified using Qt resources

Tags: qt, video, qml, vlc, libvlc

I'm trying to play .mp4 video in Qt android application using libVlc.

**Working:** When i specified **mrl** path as **mrl:"file:///home/videos/video.mp4"** it is working fine.

**not working:** when i specified **mrl** path using Qt resources(i added that .mp4 file using Qt resources) as **mrl:"qrc:///video.mp4"**
i'm getting following errors.

**core input error: open of `qrc:///video.mp4' failed
core input error: Your input can't be opened
core input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'qrc:///video.mp4'. Check the log for details.**

**code:**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QmlVlc 0.1
import QtMultimedia 5.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height/1.1

    VlcPlayer {
        id: vlcPlayer;
        mrl:"qrc:///video.mp4";
      }

    VideoOutput {
        source: vlcPlayer;
        anchors.centerIn: parent;

        anchors.top: parent.top;
        anchors.left: parent.left;
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom;
        anchors.right: parent.right;
        width: Screen.width-10 ;
        height: Screen.height-10 ;
        anchors.margins: 10
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
    MouseArea
    {
        onClicked: vlcPlayer.pause();
        onDoubleClicked: vlcPlayer.play(vlcPlayer.mrl);

    }
}
```

Please help me ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem here? Just not use "qrc" as the beginning of the MRL.

List of supported access protocols: https://wiki.videolan.org/Media_resource_locator/